# Is there a way to get "true"/"false" string values from a Boolean in PHP?

Tags: php, casting, boolean

When I cast to Boolean (using `(bool)`), is there a built in way to get PHP to actually return the constants `true` or `false`. At the moment I'm getting `1` or blank, which evaluate to true and false respectively.

I want the value returned for clearer semantics. However, if I can't get it, I'll just settle with 1 and blank.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful question if you're worried about semantics, would be how you *output* true/false values for debugging purposes - in which case, you might be more interested in, say, wrapping the `print` function or some such.

Comment: @Dav Thanks, I didn't think my problem through thoroughly. I was raw outputting, and I didn't click that I wouldn't be using these values to display in my view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP displays boolean values as 1 (true) or empty string (false) when outputted.

If you want to check if it's `true` or `false` use `==` (if implicit conversion is OK) or `===` (if it's not). For example:

```
echo $val ? 'true' : 'false'; // implicit conversion
echo $val === true ? 'true' : 'false'; // no conversion
```

I don't know of any way to make PHP output boolean values natively as `true` or `false`.

Comment: I think he's wanting the string values "true" or "false".

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't tell me anything I didn't already know. I think my question is a bit silly actually.

Comment: @fiXedd: my last sentence doesn't address that?

Answer (score 11):

In case you're too lazy to do a comparison and `echo` a string or if you just want to keep it short you can use :

```
var_export($boolean, true); // the second parameter is to return and not output
```

[PHP: var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: This should actually be the accepted answer, anyone that is asking a php question should know how to use ternary operators already. There is one thing I would add to this, however. If you want implicit conversion as is mentioned in cletus's answer, you should first cast `$boolean` to `(boolean)$boolean`. This will return `'true'` for values like `1`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the strings "true" and "false," a ternary conditional would be perfect:

```
<?=(($boolean) ? "true" : "false")?>
```