# How to have PHP boolean FALSE to be output as FALSE only

Tags: php

I am setting a PHP variable's value as false. Then after some processing I am outputting some JavaScript variables in a script. This is the code

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          var a = '.$a.';
          var b = '.$b.';
      </script>';
```

When the script finishes I get this output:

```
var a = 1;
var b = ;
```

So I get syntax error in JavaScript. Now the question is, how to have those values as true boolean values in JavaScript as well?

Intended output:

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
```

I don't want string like `'true'` or `'false'`...or 1 and 0, but boolean `true` and `false` only. Any help regarding this, also with some explanation as to why PHP behaves this way?

Comment: Look at the logic of JavaScript booleans http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html

Comment: There are similiar questions on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249235/is-there-a-way-to-get-true-false-values-from-a-boolean-in-php
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512705/print-false-in-php And all do the same by using strings instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          var a = '.($a?"true":"false").';
          var b = '.($b?"true":"false").';
      </script>';
```

I suppose, You cant simply echo true/false to get the word, You need to convert it to string.

Comment: right and when you echo it in js, the js value will hold a boolean, not a string because it won't echo with quotes around it

Answer (score 4):

Use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$a = true;
$b = false;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          var a = '.json_encode($a).';
          var b = '.json_encode($b).';
      </script>';
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way to do it would be using [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          var a = ', var_export($a), ';
          var b = ', var_export($b), ';
      </script>';
```

Comment: that's really interesting one, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Encode as JSON.

```
$ php
<?php
echo json_encode(true) . "\n";
echo json_encode(false) . "\n";             
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this would work and be easy to add:

```
($val ? "true" : "false")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the php side, and [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) on the js side to transfer variables. (json2 is included in most js frameworks)

```
<?php
$js_vars = json_encode(array(
    'a' => true,
    'b' => false,
));
?>
<script>
   JS_VARS = JSON.parse('<?php print $js_vars?>');
   console.log(JS_VARS.a, JS_VARS.b);
</script>
```

Works for single variables too, but I would recommend to group your variables so they won't pollute the javascript's global object.